# How to use this solderless conector (50 Watts COB LED)?

Tags: led, connector, cob

I bought this 50 Watts 220v COB LED at Aliexpress:

[image: 50W COB LED]

It's solderless. The connector is in the upper left corner, but I can't figure out how to connect the wires: must I depress or lift the tabs or just push the wire into?

This is the page: [50 Watts COB LED](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32891611732.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.1d6f6436ZtJX6h&algo_pvid=bf198487-9b03-4bb6-82a2-f48d201454ac&algo_exp_id=bf198487-9b03-4bb6-82a2-f48d201454ac-3&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2265707833824%22%7D&pdp_pi=-1%3B1746.0%3B-1%3B-1%40salePrice%3BCLP%3Bsearch-mainSearch)

Comment: The only thing separating the back plate of that cob from mains voltage is some microns worth of probably very cheaply made dielectric. Make absolutely certain any heatsink you attach is extremely well grounded as it could easily go live at mains voltage. Obviously a fuse is necessary too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a Chinese clone of the Wago Cage Clamp smd connector. https://www.wago.com/global/pcb-terminal-blocks-and-pluggable-connectors/smd-terminal-block-with-push-buttons-in-tape-and-reel-packing/p/2060-452_998-404

It is a simple push in design. A metal blade or spring clamps down when you do. The tabs are depressed to allow the wires to be removed.

Per the q&a section It takes 1.5 mm2 or 16 awg cable. That may be stranded or solid core but who knows.

The Wago one takes 24 to 18 awg solid or stranded or some fine stranded with ferrule.

Answer (score 1):

You just strip the wires and push them into the corresponding hole.  It looks like you press on the little tabs to release them.  Since it is line voltage, a fuse should be installed and a GFCI/RCD module would be a good idea until you can get it into a suitably insulated and/or grounded enclosure.  Also a beefy heatsink or heatspreader for that chip.

Comment: Thanks. I have an installation with both fuses and one pole rail mounted breaker.